# Iphone convert color image to 2bit image (black-white)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics

I need help to convert a color image to "black and white", not grayscale.

I what to do this with the iPhone SDK and Core Graphics, as I'm convinced this is possible.

Comment: Wouldn't black and white be a 1-bit image rather than 2? 2 bits would afford you four different colours.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible and I previously tried two paths:

1. Convert to Grayscale then apply pixel by pixel conversion to B&W.
   --Problem with this is I don't get good results with images with transparency.
2. If you're not very strict, given an RGBA image, get the pixel RGB average and convert to B&W with a supplied threshold and retain its transparency.  Technically this is still RGBA but more of Black, White and Transparency.

e.g.

```
  UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"option_bluetooth.png"];  

  unsigned char *pixelBuffer = [self getPixelData:originalImage.CGImage]; 
  size_t length = originalImage.size.width * originalImage.size.height * 4;
  CGFloat intensity;
  int bw;
  //50% threshold
  const CGFloat THRESHOLD = 0.5;
  for (int index = 0; index < length; index += 4)  
  {  
    intensity = (pixelBuffer[index] + pixelBuffer[index + 1] + pixelBuffer[index + 2]) / 3. / 255.;
    if (intensity > THRESHOLD) {
      bw = 255;
    } else {
      bw = 0;
    }
    pixelBuffer[index] = bw;


    pixelBuffer[index + 1] = bw;  
    pixelBuffer[index + 2] = bw;
  }

  CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace=CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
  CGContextRef bitmapContext=CGBitmapContextCreate(pixelBuffer, originalImage.size.width, originalImage.size.height, 8, 4*originalImage.size.width, colorSpace,  kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault);
  CFRelease(colorSpace);
  free(pixelBuffer);
  CGImageRef cgImage=CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);
  CGContextRelease(bitmapContext);

  UIImage *bwImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
```

I get the pixel data by writing to an offscreen context (the new way of getting the raw data which Apple suggests does not work for me)

e.g.

```
  CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

  unsigned char *rawData = malloc(imageHeight * imageWidth * 4);
  CGContextRef offscreenContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, imageWidth, imageHeight,
                                                        bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                                        kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault);

  CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

  CGContextDrawImage(offscreenContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight), cgCropped);
  CGContextRelease(offscreenContext);
```

Here's the code to get Pixel Data

```
+ (unsigned char *) getPixelData: (CGImageRef) cgCropped {

  size_t imageWidth = CGImageGetWidth(cgCropped);

  size_t imageHeight = CGImageGetHeight(cgCropped);
  size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
  size_t bytesPerPixel = 4;
  size_t bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * imageWidth;
  CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

  unsigned char *rawData = malloc(imageHeight * imageWidth * 4);
  CGContextRef offscreenContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, imageWidth, imageHeight,
                                                        bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                                        kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault);

  CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

  CGContextDrawImage(offscreenContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight), cgCropped);
  CGContextRelease(offscreenContext);

  return rawData;
}
```

Comment: Hi Manny , I tried this answer i am getting error as "use of undeclared identifier GraphicsUtils"  What is the necessary packages to import .. Please Guide me .. i need this Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi, GraphicUtils is a custom utility, it should be easy to get pixel data just search the net for solution.

Comment: It would be good if the method you're using was available too. I'm not sure what format that method returns the data in.

Comment: Added the code to get the pixel data. @AaronBratcher

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CGBitmapContextCreate method to get the data from an image.

Have a look at his link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/448758/1863223

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would just throw it out there that if you did not want to threshold the image, the code would look like ==>

```
intensity = (pixelBuffer[index] + pixelBuffer[index + 1] + pixelBuffer[index + 2]) / 3.0;

pixelBuffer[index] = (int)intensity;
pixelBuffer[index + 1] = (int)intensity;  
pixelBuffer[index + 2] = (int)intensity;
```