# kCGImageAlphaNone unresolved identifier in swift

Tags: ios, image-processing, swift, core-image

I am trying to convert images/textures (for SpriteKit) to grayscale with CoreImage in Swift :

I found this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17218546/836501 which I try to convert to swift for iOS7/8

But `kCGImageAlphaNone` doesn't exist. Instead I can use `CGImageAlphaInfo.None` but the function `CGBitmapContextCreate()` doesn't like it as its last parameter. I am obliged to use the enum `CGBitmapInfo` but there doesn't seem to be the `kCGImageAlphaNone` equivalent inside.

This is the full line with the wrong parameter (last one) :

```
var context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, UInt(width), UInt(height), 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone)
```

I just need a way to convert UIImage to grayscale in Swift.

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26640037/swift-opengl-unresolved-identifier-kcgimagealphapremultipliedlast.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR, do you mind answering with a copy+paste so I can accept your answer ? I guess some will try to close this question because of duplicate, but I wouldn't do it. I tried to look for my problem with the keyword `kCGImageAlphaNone` and couldn't find anything, some may do the same kind of research ;]

Comment: Would `CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Little | CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue)` work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to create a `struct CGBitmapInfo` from the `CGImageAlphaInfo.None` value:

```
let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.None.rawValue)
var context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, UInt(width), UInt(height), 8, 0, colorSpace, bitmapInfo)
```

Comment: Via [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29957352/255489): as of Swift 2.0, you can just pass `CGImageAlphaInfo.NoneSkipFirst.rawValue` directly to `CGBitmapContextCreate`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the original Objective-C code was wrong.  The `kCGImageAlphaNone` enum value was not the appropriate type to be passing, but Objective-C is less type safe (an enum is an enum) so it worked.  The raw value of `kCGImageAlphaNone` is `0`, so passing `CGBitmapInfo.allZeros` or `CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrderDefault` (both of which have raw values of `0`) should give you the same results.